# No output/Sound from my computer running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, headphones

When external sound card is unplugged:

[image]

As my headphone jack stopped working I started using an External sound card so that I can use my earphones. Initially it had an option to play sound using built-in speakers but now it doesn't show the option. The external sound card still works.

When the External sound card is plugged in:

[image]

Comment: Your images don't appear to give any more information about the issue appear to be the same image.

Comment: @George I have uploaded another pic. Hope this works!!